# How to have a click event for button in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
//This for view.....

{ "mData": "View",
                    render:function(data ,type,row){
                        return '<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view?emp_Id='+row.emp_Id+'&isView=true">View</a>';
                    },
                    /*  className: "dt-body-center",
                    orderable: false  */
                    }, 
//This is for delete
                { "mData": "Delete",
                render:function(data ,type,row){
                     /* return '<button><a id="btn" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?emp_Id='+row.emp_Id+'">Delete</a></button>'; */
                      return '<button id="delete_Id" >Delete</button>';
                },
                     className: "dt-body-center",
                    orderable: false 
                    },
```

here what i am trying to do is when i click on the button i want to get a confirm box and if i press ok the data must be deleted.I have done using ajax.The below is my source code which i have tried.I have given direct link for the edit so it working.But at the same time i want to do for click event for that ...Can i have a solution for it ?

```
//jquery

$("#delete_Id").on("click",function () {
         var val = $(this).attr('row.emp_Id');
        console.log("val:"+val);
        var myUrl = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?emp_Id='+val+' ';
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'myUrl',
                type: "POST",
                data:{"emp_Id":'row.emp_Id'},
                success: function (text) {
                   response = text;
                }
            });
            getAjaxResponce();
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the update code as bellow

```
$("#delete_Id").on("click",function () {
     var val = $(this).attr('row.emp_Id');
    console.log("val:"+val);
    var myUrl = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?emp_Id='+val+' ';
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {


       $.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data:{"emp_Id":'row.emp_Id'},
            success: function (text) {
               response = text;
            }
        });
        getAjaxResponce();
    } 
});
```

Comment: the controll is not going into the function

Comment: have you added jQuery.js?

Comment: Where you have added JS in footer or header?

Comment: in header I have added

Comment: Please move your JS in footer

Comment: Or add `$(document).ready(function() {......});` add your script in place of ......

Comment: When i am doing that it is showing error $ is not defined and $(...).DataTable is not a function

Comment: Please check is there any other error if not then add <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> before `$(document...`

Comment: when i added that i am getting this error Cannot read property 'oApi' of undefined

Comment: $("#example").on('click', '#delete_Id', function () {
  /*  var val = $(this).attr('row.emp_Id');
  console.log(row.emp_Id); */
  console.log("Hiii");
  var myUrl = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?emp_Id='+$(this).attr('empId')+'';
  var c=confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
     if (c) {
         $.ajax({
             url: myUrl,
             type: "POST",
             data:{ emp_Id : 'row.emp_Id'},
             success: function (response) {
                alert("Response from the action:"+response);
             }
         });
     } 
 });

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the on-click event after the button is rendered. Otherwise It wont work. If you can't, you have to go different solutions like this:

```
<button id="delete_Id" onclick="delete()">Delete</button>


function delete () {
     var val = $(this).attr('row.emp_Id');
    console.log("val:"+val);
    var myUrl = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?emp_Id='+val+' ';
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {


       $.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data:{"emp_Id":'row.emp_Id'},
            success: function (text) {
               response = text;
            }
        });
        getAjaxResponce();
    } 
});
```

Comment: I am getting into the function but the id is not getting deleted